# Why copyDatabase command still gives not authorized error message when 'dbAdminAnyDatabase'?

Tags: mongodb

The version is mongo 2.6.

I have created a user have role "dbAdminAnyDatabase".  But when copyDatabase still gives error message.

```
mongos> db.createUser({user:"hant",pwd:"abc",roles:["readWriteAnyDatabase","dbAdminAnyDatabase"]});
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "hant",
    "roles" : [
        "readWriteAnyDatabase",
        "dbAdminAnyDatabase"
    ]
}

mongos> use admin;
switched to db admin
mongos> db.auth("hant","abc");
1
mongos>  db.copyDatabase("wlib007","wlib003");
{
    "errmsg" : "exception: nextSafe(): { $err: \"not authorized for query on wlib007.system.namespaces\", code: 13 }",
    "code" : 13106,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

But when checking wlib007.system.namespaces.find,

```
mongos> db.system.namespaces.find();
{ "name" : "admin.system.version" }
{ "name" : "admin.system.indexes" }
{ "name" : "admin.system.version.$_id_" }
{ "name" : "admin.system.users" }
{ "name" : "admin.system.users.$_id_" }
{ "name" : "admin.system.users.$user_1_db_1" }
{ "name" : "admin.system.profile", "options" : { "capped" : true, "size" : 1048576 } }
```

Why `dbAdminAnyDatabase` role doesn't work for `copyDatabase`?

Comment: Setting permissions and copying databases are tasks for a database administrator, not a software developer. I nominated this question for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official document describing roles of mongo:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

Following the rules, "dbAdmin" has no permission to read/write. You can have a role test by client of mongodb such as Mongochef.

Answer (score 0):

As you written:

```
mongos> db.auth("hant","abc");
db.copyDatabase("wlib007","wlib003");
```

> {"errmsg" : "exception: nextSafe(): { $err: \"not authorized for query
>   on wlib007.system.namespaces\", code: 13 }","code" : 13106,
>   "ok" : 0 }

That you want

> use wlib003

create user hant and grant those **DB("wlib007","wlib003")** authentication;

as followings.

It's a simple question.

1. It's important that you must switch the target DB **NOT** admin.

> use yourDB

2. check your DB authentication by
3. show users

If you get a {} empty object that is the question. You just need to type

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "yourUser",
      pwd: "password",
      roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
    } )
```

or

```
db.grantRolesToUser('yourUser',[{ role: "dbAdmin", db: "yourDB" }])
```